# Best way to modify the result of a query before converting to excel in a Dtsx

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I have a dtsx that performs various tasks, one of them is to retrieve data from a query and convert it for saving in an excel file
Some rows have a column with duplicate data, what I should do is make a change to the aforementioned column as in the example

Before(the column in question is in yellow)
[image]

After(the desired result is the two gray cells)
[image]

I would think that to the current line if I already have an Account with the same name add the suffix _2, assuming that upstream I cannot prevent this situation, what is the best way to go? (I imagine that in the query that retrieves the data, can do anything)

**UPDATE**
I tried this query but the result didn't change

```
WITH CTE as
(
select
    pe.Code,
    pe.Name
    Fiscal_Code, 
    LastName, 
    FirstName, 
    Account,
    ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER( PARTITION By Account Order By LastName,FirstName) as RN
from 
    MyTable mt (nolock)
inner join
    People pe (nolock)
on
    (ltrim(rtrim(mt.Profile))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(mt.House)))=SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(pe.FirstName)),1,11)
where
    flag_new= 1 and
    pe.Code='A' and
    SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(pe.FirstName)),11,1)<>'-' and
    ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(pe.FirstName)),11,1))=1

union


select
    pe.Code,
    pe.Name
    Fiscal_Code, 
    LastName, 
    FirstName, 
    Account,
    ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER( PARTITION By Account Order By LastName,FirstName) as RN
from 
    MyTable mt (nolock)
inner join
    People pe (nolock)
on
    (ltrim(rtrim(mt.Profile))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(mt.House)))=SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(pe.FirstName)),1,11)
where
    flag_new= 1 and
    pe.Code='A' and
    SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(pe.FirstName)),11,1)<>'-' and
    ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(pe.FirstName)),11,1))=0

union


select
    
    pe.Code,
    pe.Name
    Fiscal_Code, 
    LastName, 
    FirstName, 
    Account,
    ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER( PARTITION By Account Order By LastName,FirstName) as RN
from 
    MyTable mt (nolock)
inner join
    People pe (nolock)
on
    (ltrim(rtrim(mt.Profile))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(mt.House)))=SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(pe.FirstName)),1,10)
where
    flag_new= 1 and
    pe.Code='A' and
    SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(pe.FirstName)),11,1)='-'


union

select 
    pe.Code,
    pe.Name
    Fiscal_Code, 
    LastName, 
    FirstName, 
    Account,
    ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER( PARTITION By Account Order By LastName,FirstName) as RN
from 
    MyTable mt (nolock)
inner join
    People pe (nolock)
on
    Code='A'
where
    flag_new= 1 and
    ltrim(rtrim(mt.Profile))= 'OFFICE 1' and
    pe.Type in ('30','31') and
    ((pe.end_validation_date is null) or (pe.end_validation_date>getdate())))
    SELECT
    pe.Code,
    pe.Name
    Fiscal_Code, 
    LastName, 
    FirstName, 
    Account+
    Case 
    when RN = 1
    then ''
    else '_' + cast(RN+1 as varchar(20))
    end as Account
    FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it can be done by using Variable object type and script component

A very bad solution is to compare the data with a string variable and add it to the variable if it doesn't exist, and add the desired prefix to the variable if it exists.
You can do it using Expression Task.

```
@[User::nametest] = FINDSTRING(@[User::nametest],","+ @[User::V_shape] +",",1)  == 0 ? @[User::nametest] + ","+ @[User::V_shape] +"," : @[User::nametest]
```

This solution may be suitable for a small number of records, but for a large number of records, it is a very bad solution